# Spring integration dynamic recipient out channel

Tags: spring-integration

Can any one tell me if the below snippet is possible?  I would like to be able to route to any number of recipients with out knowing the specific out channel.  someone else would be defining it and my process would simply need to route to it.

```
<recipient-list-router id="componentRouter" input-channel="routingChannel" 
        default-output-channel="router-out-channel-1" 
        resolution-required="false">
    <recipient channel="router-out-channel-${the selector expression}" selector-expression="payload.getChannel().contains('2')" />
</recipient-list-router>
```

I know I could use a header value router and have the message originator populate it but I would prefer finding it myself.  there are a number of places I would like to use an expression to define the out channel but that does not seem to be possible in most cases. one example where I am able to do something similar to this is with the jms channel adapter by using the "destination-expression" attribute and I would like to apply the same kind of process on the router as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right. It isn't possible with `RecipientListRouter` or even with any Mapping router, because your 'wish' breaks a 'mapping' principle.

However, the generic router (`RouterFactoryBean`), when you provide your POJO and its method, can apply a list of `MessageChannel`. Something like this:

```
<int:router input-channel="input" ref="myRouter" method="route"/>


public List<String> route(Message<?> message) {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (message.getPayload().equals("foo") || message.getPayload().equals("bar")) {
            results.add("foo-channel");
            results.add("bar-channel");
        }
        return results;
    }
```